# OpenLDAP - Get Password Attributes

Tags: java, ldap, openldap

i am writing an OpenLdap controller, where i have a lot of ldap functions. One function is to get a LdapUser and his different attributes.

For example:

```
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> enumResult = null;
    UserData ldapUser = new UserData();

    private String[] user_attributes = new String[]{"uid","cn", "sn", "dn", "description", "mail", "displayName",
        "userPassword","pwdChangedTime","pwdExpires", "lastLogonTime"};

    try
    {                  
        SearchControls searchCtrls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        searchCtrls.setReturningAttributes(user_attributes);


        String filter = "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid="+userUid+"))";

        enumResult = ctx.search(ou,filter,searchCtrls);

        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) enumResult.next();


        ldapUser.setUid(getAttribute(result,"uid"));    
        ldapUser.setCN(getAttribute(result, "cn"));
        ldapUser.setSN(getAttribute(result, "sn"));
        ldapUser.setGivenName(getAttribute(result, "givenName"));
        ldapUser.setDescription(getAttribute(result, "description"));
        ldapUser.setMail(getAttribute(result, "mail"));         

    }
```

That works fine. I have my ldapUser class fullfilled with the attributes. I did the same for a TDS Controller before, and there i could use even the following attributes:

```
        ldapUser.setPassword(getAttribute(result, "userPassword"));
        ldapUser.setpwdExpires(getAttribute(result,"pwdExpires"));
        ldapUser.setpwdChangedTime(getAttribute(result, "pwdChangedTime"));
        ldapUser.setlastLogonTime(getAttribute(result,"lastLogonTime"));
```

But it seems this doesn't work for OpenLdap anymore. Does anyone know or has a solution for getting these password attributes in java from OpenLdap?

Best regards

Comment: Do you have the `ppolicy` overlay configured?

Answer (score -2):

> The "password" is most likely either a hash of the real password or an encrypted version.

Source: [How to retrieve LDAP password via JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394233/how-to-retrieve-ldap-password-via-jndi)

See also http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/java/ldap/how-to-query-password-attribute-of-ldap-entry.html

Comment: That's not a 'ref[erence]', it is the source of your plagiarism.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for investing your valuable time. I will take care when to use 'Reference', 'Source' and 'See also'.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers. 
But i have still the problem. The attribute "userPassword" is working, but the important ones, which were working at TDS, are 

"pwdExpires", "pwdChangedTime","lastLogonTime", etc. How can i get these?

Comment: As @EJP suggested, did you configured overlay [ppolicy](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html).